# How to stop removeChild() from making other siblings move upwards?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a single page application, when I open many windows(div's) and close one all of those windows go upwards. I made the position relative for the window in the css (.newchat) so that when I open many they stack nicely. But I think it's making this bug when closing one of them. However, the bug goes away when changing the window position to absolute. But this will not make them on top of each other just like book pages.

here is my css where body is the parent

```
 body {
background: #e9e9e9;
color: #9a9a9a;
font: 100%/1.5em "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
position: relative; 
height: 985px;
width: 100%;
}
.newchat{
 position: relative;  
z-index: 30; 
width: 20%;
height: 7em;
font-size: 12px;
width: 300px;
opacity: 0.9
}
```

app.js for closing windows

```
  document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   var ele = e.target
   if (ele.id === ('chat-close')) {
   ele.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(ele.parentNode.parentNode)
return false
}
})
```

Comment: Maybe set visibility: hidden; instead of using remove child

Comment: Yep, either what @user2887596 said would work, or alternately, you could wrap the content of each "window" in an additional <div>, and called removeChild on *that* div, rather than the container. That way, the container stays there, and remains the same height, keeping all the following elements in the same Y position relative to their container, while still removing the *content* of the window.